# Is there a way knowing what hash-algorithm is used?

Tags: algorithm, codeigniter, passwords

Is there a way knowing what hash-algorithm is used?

My question is grounded of that I've got an database from a customer with some users and passwords. I have no idea what the passwords are (so it's correctly stored in the database) and the customer would not like to give these passwords away (it's understandable)

I have access to the database and I know that the passwordhash is 60 characters long, but nothing else.

I basically want to create a new user (directly in the database if possible) with a temporary password so I can login to the system - but it's kind of impossible if I don't know how to create the password. Any thoughts?

The system is created in CodeIgniter but I don't know what authentification-method is used.

Comment: You have to take into account if the system is using some salt mechanism besides the hashing, so knowing just the hashing algorithm could may not  be enough

Comment: @higuaro - yeah that's true! Thanks for pointing that out! But If would know the authenficaiton method it might give me a clue what library is used for the authentificiation.

Comment: it can be `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` [REF](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) but no one can guarantee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What data do the passwords contain? Do they contain only 0-9 and a-f, i.e. hex 
values, or can they contain other data too? If you want to know the algorithm, it is crucial to answer to this question.

If they contain hex values only, 60*4 = 240 and there is no common algorithm
which gives a hash that is 240 bits long.

It has been suggested that the password contains salt, which might explain the
unusual length.

Why not ask the customer what has algorithm is used? It is understandable that 
the customer doesn't want to give away these passwords, but there should be no 
objection to giving away the hash algorithm.

Comment: They can contain all type of values ($, 2, a, ./). They seem to contain characters in the alphabet, numbers, dollar-signs and slashes only but I'm not sure if they are restricted to those characters.  If I could ask the customer that (and get a good answer) I wouldn't put the question here :-)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, values encrypted by bcrypt begin with $2a$ so that might be a good guess for the hash algorithm.